# FadeIn Animation to Validations- Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I want to add Fade-in transition to validation labels in Angular-

```
   <form [formGroup]="regForm">
      <div formGroupName="teamdetails">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="teamname">Team Name:</label>
          <label class="validations" *ngIf="!regForm.get('teamdetails.teamname').valid && regForm.get('teamdetails.teamname').touched">Please Enter a Valid Team Name!</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="teamname" id="teamname" required placeholder="Enter Your Team Name">
        </div>
```

I want them to appear with opacity transition, I tried   `$('label').fadeIn(2000);` in jQuery but didn't work.

Comment: you are using angular so try its module. You can use BrowserAnimationsModule for animations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this animation to your component decorator:

```
animations:[ trigger('load', [
        transition(':enter', [
            style({ opacity: 0 }),
            animate(600, style({ opacity: 1 }))
        ]),
        transition(':leave', [
            style({ opacity: 1 }),
            animate(600, style({ opacity: 0 }))
        ])

    ])
  ]
```

andand then in the view :

```
  <label @load style="color:red" *ngIf="myModel.invalid">INVALID</label>
```

Don't forget to add this to the module:

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
```

....

```
  imports:      [ ...., BrowserAnimationsModule ],
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hbai4s?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Comment: hi, i have asked new question about animations, wondering if you could answer

Comment: See my answer please